# Silverstripe 3.1: How to know which classes are decorated by a DataExtension

Tags: php, design-patterns, silverstripe

I've got an extension, say:

```
class UselessExtension extends DataExtension {
   public function sayHello() {
      echo "hello";
   }
}
```

I use it to extend two classes through a YAML config:

```
Member:
  extensions:
    - UselessExtension
MyDataObject:
  extensions:
    - UselessExtension
```

Is there anywhere in SilverStripe a function to call in order to know which classes are extended by my UselessExtension?

I'm searching for something like

```
DataExtension::getDecoratedBy('UselessExtension');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no built in method for that so you'll need to write your own.

Something similar to this should work:

```
function getDecoratedBy($extension){
    $classes = array();
    foreach(ClassInfo::subClassesFor('Object') as $className) {
        if (Object::has_extension($className, $extension)){
            $classes[] = $classname;
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was searching for, thanks a lot. It's quite a bit a performance killer, but I have to use it in a background task, so it't not a big issue.

Comment: Agreed it is a performance killer. This should not be used in a loop, or the outcome of this function should be cached in memory to improve performances.